# using set for sorting in log(N)?

Tags: c++, data-structures

Is the time complexity of the whole code O(log(N))? ( In amortized). And If,so can we use this method for sorting, every time? Initially there was need to sort some numbers.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 

    int numbers[]={60 , 2 , 3 , 35, 67, 111, 5, 7};
    set<int> s (numbers,numbers+8);
    for(auto x : s)
    {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h> 
using namespace std; 
` Please stop doing that.

Comment: Tip : `std::begin` and `std::end` give you iterators for arrays : `set<int> s (std::begin(numbers),std::end(numbers));` It avoid magic numbers (`+8` here) or calculating size yourself (like `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(*numbers)`).

Comment: Technically no complexity. Code doesn't compile: https://godbolt.org/z/Q0XvCy

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Per [[set.cons]\4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/set.cons#4) the iterator constructors of `std::set` has a

> *Complexity:* Linear in `N` if the range `[first, last)` is already sorted using `comp` and otherwise `N log N` , where `N` is `last - first`.

So in your case you still have `N log N` complexity since `numbers` is not sorted and it's not any different from just using `std::sort` like

```
int main() 
{ 

    int numbers[]={60 , 2 , 3 , 35, 67, 111, 5, 7};
    std::sort(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers));
    for(auto x : numbers)
    {
        cout << x << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

except that in the case of using a set you need to allocate nodes so you have all of that cost added.

Answer (score 4):

> Is the time complexity of the whole code O(log(N))?

No, it is not.

```
set<int> s {60 , 2 , 3 , 35, 67, 111, 5, 7};
```

is a shortcut for:

```
set<int> s;
s.insert(60);

...

s.insert(7);
```

The complexity of each `insert` is `O(log(size()))`. From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/insert:

> **Complexity**
>   1-2) Logarithmic in the size of the container, O(log(size())).

The complexity of the whole operation is `O(N * log(N))`.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, the complexity of your code as a whole is constant. There is no `n` that you could increase to observe increased runtime.

I guess what you actually refer to is: Sorting `n` integers via constructing a `std::set`. In that case you need to consider that the complexity of that constructor is O(n log(n)) (if the input is not already sorted, see eg [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set). Compare that to sorting a `std::vector` (or some other container) via `std::sort`, which is O(n log(n)) as well, you dont gain here by using a `std::set`.

Answer (score 2):

The time complexity is log(n), where n = no of elements in set, for each insert operation. So for inserting all the elements, the overall time complexity would be nlog(n) unless you explicitly specify the optimal position for inserting the element, then in that case it will be amortized constant.